# How to get Screen-On Time on Windows Phone 7.5?

Tags: windows-phone-7, screen

How to get the total Screen-On Time since charged on Windows Phone 7.5?

Answer (score 2):

The current Windows Phone APIs do not provide access to this kind of information. It isn't accessible from within the OS at all, so I doubt if this data is available to the OS.